# Why do I have to delete and reinstall all node modules every time I restart my PC?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Every time I reboot my computer, I have to delete the node_modules folder and re-install using `NPM install` - is there a way to fix this?

The issue that happens is the webserver refuses to start, saying that there are modules missing - the module it thinks is missing seems to change each time randomly I guess based on whichever it looks for first. Here's an example error message:

```
[nodemon] starting `node start.js`
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './middleware/query'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GoogleDrive\University\EL600\Code\kentnetmon\node_                                                          modules\express\lib\application.js:20:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GoogleDrive\University\EL600\Code\kentnetmon\node_                                                          modules\express\lib\express.js:17:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is really annoying and could mean broken or hard-to-install deployed builds.

Comment: Are you doing any read/write/deletes at any point in your project?  Are you accidentally deleting files?

Comment: No, unless a package is doing something I'm unaware of, the only read/write is to a mongoose database

Comment: have you tried moving your stuff out of google drive?

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Actually you know what, I think it worked. Thanks @JohannesMerz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the files out of Google Drive and do the delete-reinstall step one more time and it should work from now on!